# How to call a REST function from an Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

Is it possible to call an Azure Function from an Azure Policy ?
Assume a function that returns a boolean based on a ResourceId. The function looks up the resource and decides if the resource contains a tag with a certain name and if the tag conforms to a set list of values. If the tag conforms, the resource returns true, otherwise false.
Consider the policy below and note the PCODE section.

Is something like this possible ? I can find no documentation or samples allowing this.

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value",
      "policyType": "BuiltIn",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value.",          
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
//ORIGINAL IN SAMPLE
            "not": {
               "field": "MyTagName",
               "equals": "Sample Tag Value"
            }
//PCODE TO CALL FUNCTION
            "not": {
               "evaluate": "https://url.../ReturnsBoolean/resourceId()"
            }
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   },
   "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62",
   "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
   "name": "1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible using azure policy as it exists today.

The following document shows you the policy functions that azure policy supports: 
[policy-functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-functions)